# Vue: v-model in nested v-for-loop

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for, v-model

I am stuck with a nested for loop and a v-model inside it. I have no problems updating the data inside the first for-loop (row.amount), but when I change the input member.share for John in one row, all of John's shares are updated?

my component:

```
<div v-for="row in rows">
   …
   <input type="text" v-model="row.amount" />
   <div v-for="member in row.teams">
      <input type="text" v-model="member.share" />
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the data:

```
rows: [
{
    amount: 100,
    team: [
        {
            name: John,
            share: 0
        },
        {
            name: Jane,
            share: 0
        }
    ] 
},
{
    amount: 299,
    team: [
        {
            name: John,
            share: 0
        },
        {
            name: Jane,
            share: 0
        }
    ] 
}
]
```

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zpdzqK?editors=1010

Comment: This is weird. Is there a difference between the data in a component and the data in the vue-app itself? This is the only difference I can see

Comment: Data in a component should be a function that returns the data object, but otherwise no. I updated the pen to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, i have it that way

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is related to a typo:

You're looping through `member in row.teams` but there is no `s` in the json provided. Try replacing your loop for `member in row.team`.